# Routing doesn't work for me when doing a hard refresh

Tags: angular, angular-dart, angular2-routing

I was looking at this source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/toh-5/dart/lib/app_component.dart

and it seems that my application will route right now when i go to the root.

localhost:8080/

The routing updates as i move around my application, but it seems that if i am at something:  `localhost:8080/dashboard` in a basecase, and do a hard refresh, it fails.  It will give me a `404 not found!` error.

It will work just find if i do: `localhost:8080/#!/dashboard` but that is not the address passed into my application.

In the index.html i have: `<base href="/">`

My App_Component.dart file is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';

import 'hero_component.dart';
import 'heroes_component.dart';
import 'dashboard_component.dart';
import 'hero_service.dart';
@Component(
    selector: "my-app",
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: const [HeroService, ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: "app_component.html")
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "Dashboard",
      component: DashboardComponent,
      useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(
      path: "/detail/:id", name: "HeroDetail", component: HeroDetailComponent),
  const Route(path: "/heroes", name: "Heroes", component: HeroesComponent)
])
class AppComponent {
  String title = "Tour of Heroes";
}
```

It seems I have routing working for everything except this.

My desired end state would be doing:  localhost:8080/detail/14 and it would open the correct component.  This is something that isnt done now on a fresh site reference as much as when navigating throughout the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To switch to `HashLocationStrategy` change the providers  to

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HeroService, 
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy)
])
```

If you want to use `PathLocationStrategy` you can use this `pub serve`-wrapper https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_serve_rewrites that allows to use `PathLocationStrategy` with `pub serve`.

For deployment you need to configure the webserver you use there to support HTML5 pushState.

Comment: Perfect! Works great.  I was researching and noticed it in here: https://github.com/ng2-dart-samples/router/blob/master/web/main.dart too.  I like this answer the most.

Comment: You can also use for example nginx as proxy for development instead of pub_serve_rewrites. Yup, Kasper was quite active in the Angular2 dart community. Seems he's currently busy with his math studies :-/

Answer (score 1):

Routes exist only in your app, server does not know anything, it just checks path `/dashboard` or `/detail/14` for default page/file which does not exist.

You have to configure server router to navigate to app index.html (your html name here) for all your app routes.

Answer (score 0):

If `localhost:8080/#/dashboard` works but `localhost:8080/dashboard` fails, it suggests you're using `HashLocationStrategy` rather than `PathLocationStrategy`.

Checking your `bootstrap()` function or somewhere else, make sure no `HashLocationStrategy` is injected.